# How to replace dataframes column value for all the csv files in a folder by other dataframe column value?

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe **sheet1**

```
Id  Snack      Price   
5   Orange      55    
7   Apple       53    
8   Muskmelon   33
```

I have the other dataframe **replace**

```
 Snack        Cat
   Orange      a    
   Apple       b    
   Muskmelon   c
```

For replacing column value with other column value this is the code

sheet1['snack'] = sheet1['snack'].map(replace.set_index('Snack')['Cat'])

So I will get this after the above code.

```
 Id  Snack      Price   
    5   a      55    
    7   b      53    
    8   c      33
```

How do I do the same operation for all the csv sheets present in the folder.

Input: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/1mbgjtrr6t069w1/AADC3ZrRZf33QBil63m1mxz_a?dl=0

Output: Replace Snack column sheet values with replace dataframe cat values for all the files in a folder.

Comment: what format will all the csv sheets be stored in? how many sheets will be there (aprox) ? from the link you provided there are only two sheets there - sheet1 and sheet2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you need [`glob`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html) for list of files, then loop and create DataFrame, `map` and last save back:

```
import glob

s = replace.set_index('Snack')['Cat']

for file in glob.glob('files/*.csv'):
    #df = pd.read_csv(file)
    df['Snack'] = df['Snack'].map(s)
    df.to_csv(f'{file}', index=False)
```

Comment: @panda - Can you explain more?

Comment: Snack column in the file values are not replaced

Comment: @panda - are real files confidental?

Comment: Yes If it worked with this sample data it should work can you try running it once.

Comment: @panda - You can check dtypes of `Snack` column id same in `print (replace['Snack'].dtype)` and `print (df['Snack'].dtype)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181996/discussion-between-panda-and-jezrael).